# python request.push : how to post data

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, request, postman

Hi I have installed postman and I can post data to my server now I need to post data in python code. here is the postman:
[image]

and it is working I can post the data so I want to know how I can post it in my python using request. post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend the `requests` [library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Here is [the documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.post) for creating POST requests.

```py
import requests

post_headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
post_data = {'userIds[0]' : 'A', 'userIds[1]' : 'B'}

resp = requests.post('url', headers=post_headers, json=post_data)
```

If you have something like and `Auth-Token`, include it in the `post_headers`.

Comment: I didn't. I could guess why others would though; a Google search would have sufficed to get your answer.